# variáveis no mysql: declare, set, como pegar um elemento de uma tabela

Tags: mysql, sql

Falando em variáveis que se podem declarar dentro do `begin`, eu vi que tem Declare e set só que eu não sei quando usar as mesmas. Vi que tem `set @x`, `set x`, `set x = x+1`, `set x := x+1`; todas elas me confundem e não sei para que servem direito.

Tenho esse código que é para pegar o código do produto que cada cliente mais comprou. Queria que ele pegasse o primeiro cliente de cada código e mostrasse, porque ordenei de forma desc.

Está saindo assim: nomeProduto, codigoProd, cliente, qtdComprada;

```
ABAJUR             15    JOSE TAVARES DE OLUVEIRA    2

LAPISEIRA 1.2      10    JOSE TAVARES DE OLUVEIRA    1

CAIXA DE SOM       16    JOSE TAVARES DE OLUVEIRA    1

CANETA VERMELHA     3    MANOEL JOAQUIM PURTUGA      2

LAPISEIRA 0.9       9    MANOEL JOAQUIM PURTUGA      1
```

Queria mostrar a primeira linha de cada cliente.

```
   /*Crie uma store procedure que informe o produto mais comprado de cada cliente*/
    DELIMITER $$
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS uspProdutoMaisCompradoCliente $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE uspProdutoMaisCompradoCliente () 

    BEGIN

    DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE vNomeProd VARCHAR(250);
    DECLARE vNomeCli VARCHAR(250);
    DECLARE vQtdComprProd INT(11);
    DECLARE contador int;

    DECLARE cursor_a CURSOR FOR (
    select produto.nome as nomeProd, cliente.nome as cliente,
    count(produto.codigo) as qtdComprProd
    from cliente
    inner join nota_fiscal
    on cliente.codigo = nota_fiscal.cod_cliente
    inner join item_nota_fiscal
    on item_nota_fiscal.numero_nf = nota_fiscal.numero_nf
    inner join produto
    on produto.codigo = item_nota_fiscal.cod_produto
    group by produto.nome , produto.codigo , cliente.nome , cliente.codigo
    order by cliente.nome, qtdComprProd desc
    );

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done = TRUE;

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tempTabela;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempTabela (
       tNomeProd VARCHAR(250),
      tNomeCli VARCHAR(250),
       tQtdComprProd INT(11)
    );

    OPEN cursor_a;

    REPEAT
    FETCH  cursor_a INTO vNomeProd,vNomeCli, vQtdComprProd;

    IF NOT done THEN

         INSERT INTO tempTabela VALUES (vNomeProd, vNomeCli, vQtdComprProd);

    END IF;

    UNTIL done END REPEAT;
    close cursor_a;
    SELECT * FROM tempTabela;
    END $$
    DELIMITER ;

`tabelas`:
`CREATE TABLE ESTADO (
  ESTADO VARCHAR(02) NOT NULL,
  NOME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ESTADO)
) ;`

`CREATE TABLE CIDADE (
  CODIGO INTEGER NOT NULL,
  NOME VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  ESTADO VARCHAR(02),
  PRIMARY KEY (CODIGO),
  FOREIGN KEY (ESTADO) REFERENCES ESTADO (ESTADO)
) ;`

`CREATE TABLE CLIENTE (
  CODIGO INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  NOME VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  RUA VARCHAR(250),
  NUMERO VARCHAR(10),
  COD_CIDADE INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY (CODIGO),
  FOREIGN KEY (COD_CIDADE) REFERENCES CIDADE (CODIGO)
);`

`CREATE TABLE FORNECEDOR (
  CODIGO INTEGER NOT NULL,
  NOME VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  RUA VARCHAR(250),
  NUMERO VARCHAR(10),
  COD_CIDADE INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY (CODIGO),
  FOREIGN KEY (COD_CIDADE) REFERENCES CIDADE (CODIGO)
);`

`CREATE TABLE PRODUTO (
  CODIGO INTEGER NOT NULL,
  NOME VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  PCO_ATUAL_CPA DECIMAL(10,2),
  PCO_ATUAL_VDA DECIMAL(10,2),
  QTD_ESTOQUE INTEGER,
  QTD_EST_MIN INTEGER,
  QTD_EST_MAX INTEGER,
  QTD_PTO_CPA INTEGER,
  IDF_ATIVO_SN VARCHAR(01) DEFAULT 'S',
  COD_FORNECEDOR INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY (CODIGO),
  FOREIGN KEY (COD_FORNECEDOR) REFERENCES FORNECEDOR (CODIGO)
) ;`

`CREATE TABLE NOTA_FISCAL (
  NUMERO_NF INTEGER NOT NULL,
  DTA_VENDA DATE NOT NULL,
  COD_CLIENTE INTEGER,
  VALOR_TOTAL DECIMAL(10,2),
  PRIMARY KEY (NUMERO_NF),
  FOREIGN KEY (COD_CLIENTE) REFERENCES CLIENTE (CODIGO)
) ;`

`CREATE TABLE ITEM_NOTA_FISCAL (
  NUMERO_NF INTEGER NOT NULL,
  COD_PRODUTO INTEGER NOT NULL,
  QTD_VEDIDA INTEGER,
  PCO_RECEBIDO DECIMAL(10,2),
  PRIMARY KEY (NUMERO_NF, COD_PRODUTO),
  FOREIGN KEY (NUMERO_NF) REFERENCES NOTA_FISCAL (NUMERO_NF),
  FOREIGN KEY (COD_PRODUTO) REFERENCES PRODUTO (CODIGO)
) ;`
```

Comment: Se o seu requisito é apenas esse: `pegar o código do produto que cada cliente mais comprou` você está usando um overkill para resolver o problema, um consulta simulando o `ROW_NUMBER() over` resolve seu problema. Para fazer isso preciso só conhecer seus dados e a estrutura de suas tabelas.

Comment: Eu tenho que pegar:

             ABAJUR             15    JOSE TAVARES DE OLUVEIRA    2

             CANETA VERMELHA     3    MANOEL JOAQUIM PURTUGA      2
ou seja , o primeiro cliente com seus dados, porque só assim terei acesso ao produto mais comprado de cada cliente

Comment: Por favor, adicione a estrutura das tabelas envolvidas com os dados! Só assim poderei fazer um consulta que retorne o que você espera. Os dados que você mostra na pergunta parecem vir dos joins da consulta na procedure.

Comment: Certo.Vou fazer isso.Obg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dada a sua estrutura é preciso encontrar a quantidade de produtos comprados por cada cliente, isso envolve o campo `QTD_VEDIDA` da tabela `ITEM_NOTA_FISCAL` então um simples `count` no produto não irá lhe retornar a informação correta.

Primeiro eu utilizei a sua própria query para listar a quantidade de produtos comprados por cliente.

```
select p.nome as nomeProd,
       p.codigo, 
       c.nome as cli,
       c.codigo as codcli,
       sum(inf.qtd_vedida) as qtdComprProd
  from cliente c
       inner join nota_fiscal nf on c.codigo = nf.cod_cliente
       inner join item_nota_fiscal inf on inf.numero_nf = nf.numero_nf
       inner join produto p on p.codigo = inf.cod_produto
group by p.nome, p.codigo, c.nome, c.codigo
order by c.nome, qtdComprProd desc;
```

A partir daí eu criei uma VIEW para facilitar a consulta que irá te dar o dado desejado, o produto mais comprado por cliente:

```
create or replace view vw_cli_prod_qtd as 
select p.nome as nomeProd,
       p.codigo, 
       c.nome as cli,
       c.codigo as codcli,
       sum(inf.qtd_vedida) as qtdComprProd
  from cliente c
       inner join nota_fiscal nf on c.codigo = nf.cod_cliente
       inner join item_nota_fiscal inf on inf.numero_nf = nf.numero_nf
       inner join produto p on p.codigo = inf.cod_produto
group by p.nome, p.codigo, c.nome, c.codigo
order by c.nome, qtdComprProd desc;
```

Depois é só fazer um join da view com o `MAX` da quantidade comprada por cliente, lembrando que se um cliente comprar dois produtos diferentes na mesma quantidade a consulta irá trazer os dois registros.

```
select v1.* 
  from vw_cli_prod_qtd v1
        inner join (
            select codcli, max(qtdComprProd) qtd
              from vw_cli_prod_qtd
             group by codcli 
        ) v2 on (v1.codcli = v2.codcli and v1.qtdComprProd = v2.qtd)
```

Você pode ver tudo funcionando aqui: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82ac0/1

**EDIT**

Uma view nada mais é do que um objeto de banco de dados que representa um conjunto de dados a partir de um `select`.

Como exemplo, imagine que você tem uma consulta que envolve muitas tabelas, muitos joins, muitos left joins, etc. E é uma consulta que você usa frequentemente. Ao invés de você escrever essa consulta gigante todas as vezes que precisar usá-la, você criará uma view que representa essa consulta. Vamos a um exemplo prático:

Imagine a seguinte consulta:

```
select a.campo1, b.campo2, c.campo3, d.campo4, e.qtd
  from tabelaA a 
         INNER JOIN tabelaB ON (a.id = b.aid)
         INNER JOIN tabelaC ON (b.id = c.bid)
         INNER JOIN tabelaD ON (c.id = d.did)
         LEFT JOIN (select campo1, count(*) qtd 
                      from outraTabela
                     group by campo1) e 
                ON (a.campo1 = e.campo1)
 where d.data between a.dt_inicio and a.dt_fim
```

Ao invés de você redigitar toda essa consulta, toda vez que precisar dela, você simplesmente criará uma VIEW para representar toda essa consulta, dessa forma:

```
create or replace view MINHA_VIEW_EVITA_MUITA_DIGITACAO AS
select a.campo1, b.campo2, c.campo3, d.campo4, e.qtd
  from tabelaA a 
         INNER JOIN tabelaB ON (a.id = b.aid)
         INNER JOIN tabelaC ON (b.id = c.bid)
         INNER JOIN tabelaD ON (c.id = d.did)
         LEFT JOIN (select campo1, count(*) qtd 
                      from outraTabela
                     group by campo1) e 
                ON (a.campo1 = e.campo1)
 where d.data between a.dt_inicio and a.dt_fim
```

E ao precisar usar essa query de novo, você precisará apenas fazer o select na sua view, dessa forma:

```
select campo1, campo2, campo3, campo4, qtd
  from MINHA_VIEW_EVITA_MUITA_DIGITACAO
```

Sua view passa a ser uma tabela a partir de uma query e pode ser utilizada como tabela, claro que não para insert, update ou delete existem outros tipos de view para isso.

Uma boa referência sobre views: [Trabalhando com Views](http://www.devmedia.com.br/mysql-trabalhando-com-views-parte-01/8724)

Quanto as variáveis, elas são utilizadas para armazenar valores temporariamente durante o ciclo de execução de uma procedure.

Funcionam exatamente igual a uma variável de uma linguagem de programação qualquer.

Quanto a sua definição, elas podem ser definidas das formas que você utilizou em diferentes situações:

Quando você define uma variável com `set @a := 1` ou `set @a = 1` (tanto faz `=` ou `:=`) você está atribuindo o valor `1` à variavel `@a` e ela existirá no escopo da sessão de sua conexão, o que significa dizer que você poderá executar uma atribuição e utilizar essa variável em um comando sql na mesma sessão (conexão) por exemplo:

```
mysql> SET @t1=1, @t2=2, @t3:=4;
mysql> SELECT @t1, @t2, @t3, @t4 := @t1+@t2+@t3;
+------+------+------+--------------------+
| @t1  | @t2  | @t3  | @t4 := @t1+@t2+@t3 |
+------+------+------+--------------------+
|    1 |    2 |    4 |                  7 | 
+------+------+------+--------------------+
```

Uma variavél criada sem o `@` é normalmente em um bloco anônimo (`begin ... código end;`) ou dentro de uma procedure ou função, nesses dois casos, no MySql o `declare` serve para indicar que a variável existe e o `set` para atribuir um valor a ela, por exemplo:

```
delimiter $$ --sintaxe obrigatória para mysql
begin
    declare varA int; -- criei a variável varA
    set varA = 1; -- atribui o valor 1 a varA
end$$
delimiter;
```

Outro exemplo:

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE simpleproc (OUT param1 INT)
BEGIN
   declare x int;
   SELECT COUNT(*) INTO param1 FROM t; --digamos que retorne 3
   set x = 10;
   set param1 = param1 + x;
END//
delimiter ;

CALL simpleproc(@a);
SELECT @a;
+------+
| @a   |
+------+
| 13   |
+------+
```

Veja que eu defini uma variável de sessão e uma variável de procedure nesse segundo exemplo, a variável de sessão é passada para a procedure por referência e volta com o valor preenchido depois do select.

Espero que tenha entendido.

Comment: Eu ainda não estudei esse conceito de view e tenho que fazer rodar com uma procedure, é possível? Vc pode me exlicar os conceitos de declaração de variável que perguntei no início? Obg!!

Comment: @Gabriella Editei com mais detalhes.