# View com store procedure, mysql

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma `procedure` correta e uma `view` que usa o parametro da procedure, só que a view não ve o parametro da procedure, como fazer para resolver esse problema?

**Crie uma store procedure que apartir do codigo do cliente consiga obter o valor total de compras com desconto de 10%**

```
delimiter $$
drop view if exists visao  $$
create view visao as select n.cod_cliente as codCli, (sum(i.qtd_vedida * i.pco_recebido)*0.9) as valorTotal
        from nota_fiscal as n, item_nota_fiscal as i
        where n.numero_nf = i.numero_nf and n.cod_cliente = AQUI SERIA O PARÂMETRO DA PROCEDURE, SÓ QUE A PROCEDURE VEM DEPOIS E ELE NÃO CONSEGUE PEGAR O PARÂMETRO, EXISTE ALGUMA SOLUÇÃO??(pCodCli )
        group by codCli $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS uspDesconto $$
CREATE PROCEDURE uspDesconto (pCodCli int(11))

BEGIN
  DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE vCodCli, vQtd_vedida int(11);  
  DECLARE vValorTotal decimal(10,2);
  DECLARE cont integer;

  declare cursor_a cursor for  select * from visao;

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done = TRUE;
  set cont = 0;

  DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_Prod_Forn;
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_Prod_Forn (
        tmpCodCli int(11),
        tmpValorTotal decimal(10,2)
  );

  OPEN cursor_a;
  REPEAT FETCH cursor_a INTO vCodCli, vValorTotal;
     IF NOT done THEN
        insert into tmp_Prod_Forn values(vCodCli, vValorTotal);
        -- set cont = cont + 1;
     END IF;

  UNTIL (done) END REPEAT;
  close cursor_a;

  SELECT * FROM tmp_Prod_Forn;
END $$

delimiter ;
```

Comment: Você ta criando uma view dentro da procedure?

Comment: em cima a view e abaixo a procedure, se eu nãi tivesse que chamar um parametro, o código funcionaria normal, mas tenho que eter esse parametro e não sei como chamar

Comment: Mal pergunte, porque a view precisa pegar o parametro da procedure? De onde vem esse parametro?

Comment: é para ver se o codigo do cliente que existe na tabela é iguala ao passado na chamada da procedure

Comment: Você não precisa criar uma view pra checar isso. Verifique dentro da propria procedure atraves de um if...else ou na logica da aplicacao.

Comment: Talvez o @rray possa ajudar você nessa melhor, procedure no mysql eu não manjo muito.

Comment: o que é @rray? desde já agradeço!

Comment: De qual parâmetro você está falando? Em qual momento da sua procedure a view deveria ver o parâmetro? Lembre que uma view é uma tabela (tabela virtual) se você precisa passar alguma coisa para ela, seria através do where.

Comment: o parametro pCodCli que tem lá na procedure. A view precisa dele para exibri a consulta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sabendo que uma view é o mesmo que uma tabela, como expliquei na [resposta da sua pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/91597/13286) a única coisa que precisa fazer é utilizar esse parâmetro como se fosse um filtro para a query na view, então, na hora de criar o cursor, simplesmente utilize o parâmetro no where da query na view:

```
declare cursor_a cursor for  select * from visao where codCli = pCodCli;
```

**EDIT**

Vendo sua edição percebi onde está o código do parâmetro.

Sua view então deverá ser criada da seguinte forma:

```
create view visao as 
    select n.cod_cliente as codCli, 
          (sum(i.qtd_vedida * i.pco_recebido)*0.9) as valorTotal
      from nota_fiscal as n, 
           item_nota_fiscal as i
     where n.numero_nf = i.numero_nf 
     group by codCli $$
```

Não é necessário Adicionar o parâmetro direto na view, esta view funcionará como uma tabela que terá o seguinte formato:

```
"Tabela" visao
  codCli
  valorTotal
```

Então, tudo que você precisará fazer é usar o campo `codCli` que é o mesmo campo `n.cod_cliente` que você estava tentando usar. O que você está fazendo aqui é colocando o filtro para ser usado fora da view. Então é só usar a view como informado antes aqui:

```
declare cursor_a cursor for  select * from visao where codCli = pCodCli;
```

Comment: mas no caso eu teria que tirar o where da view e colocá-lo no select * from visao? assim

Comment: drop view if exists visao  $$
create view visao as select n.cod_cliente as codCli, (sum(i.qtd_vedida * i.pco_recebido)*0.9) as valorTotal
        from nota_fiscal as n, item_nota_fiscal as i
        group by codCli $$

Comment: mas da um resultadoe estranho

Comment: Não. Entenda que a view baseada em uma consulta é como se fosse uma tabela, uma virtualização daquela consulta como se fosse uma nova tabela.  Se você tem uma tabela x e ela tem os registros A, B e C, daí você cria uma view assim: `select campo from tabela where campo in ('a','b')` significa que sua view é uma tabela que só tem os registros A e B então se você fizer `select * from viewcriada where campo=C` irá retornar nenhum registro.

Comment: Se o resultado está estranho significa que sua procedure não está fazendo o que deveria fazer corretamente ousua view não está retornando apenas o que deveria retornar!

Comment: mas a view necessita de um where e esse where necessita do registro pCodCli, não sei mais o que faço!

Comment: Editei a resposta @Gabriella veja se consegue entender.

Comment: Obg Jorge Campos!